# How to plot histogram in R based on frequency

Tags: r, histogram

Lets say I have a table like this

```
Count   MyValue
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
5       6
4       7
3       8
2       9
1       10
```

If I create a histogram of `MyValue` it looks like this:
[image]

What I want is a histogram of `MyValue` that, that also considers the `Count`.
It should look like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you expect as the result, but maybe this:

```
hist(rep(DF$MyValue, DF$Count))
```

Comment: I edit my question a little bit. But what you posted is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!